# Showing All Taxonomy Terms count based on a given contextual filter

Tags: views

I need to create a `view` that shows All **Taxonomy Terms count** from a `vocabulary` based on a `contextual filter` given.

The `contextual filter` I'm to be passed are Regions and Regions are `taxonomy terms` as well so I pass the term name via URL and the contextual filter will then convert the term name to term id and it's working fine and it's already showing the list of Taxonomy Terms and their count (See pic 2).

My problem is that it's only showing terms that's been used, I need to show all terms even terms that hasn't been used or have 0 result on count. I already supplied 'No Result Behaviors' on the fields yet it's still not showing. Can someone help me on this one? Thanks!

[image: View]

[image: ResulT]

Answer (score 1):

You Did your jobs correctly but you have only one mistake, you should create  views according to **nodes then relate it to taxonomy** instead create **taxonomy view then relate it to nodes**.
I explain my mean by example

**Nid           title         termid**
1           title1       55
2           title2       43
3           title3       55
4          title4        --
5          title6       16

So when  there is not set termid view has a row result with no termid then this mean you can  put 0 value in  "No result"

Comment: Thanks zhilevan. But whenever I add a contextual filter it still only lists the taxonomy terms that has a node related to it.  Anyone knows what's the best way to do this one? Thanks!

Comment: @BoinxFlags read my answer precisely please,It work with contextual or any else filter.